# Using StreamingHttpResponse with Django Rest Framework CSV

Tags: python, django, rest, csv, django-rest-framework

I have a standard DRF web application that outputs CSV data for one of the routes. Rendering the entire CSV representation takes a while to do. The data set is quite large so I wanted to have a streaming HTTP response so the client doesn't time out.

However using the example provided in https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/blob/2ff49cff4b81827f3f450fd7d56827c9671c5140/rest_framework_csv/renderers.py#L197 doesn't quite accomplish this. The data is still one large payload instead of being chunked and the client ends up waiting for a response before the bytes are received.

The structure is similar to what follows:

**models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):
  count = models.PostiveIntegerField(blank=True)
  ...
```

**renderers.py**

```
class ReportCSVRenderer(CSVStreamingRenderer):
  header = ['count']
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  count = fields.IntegerField()

  class Meta:
    model = Report
```

**views.py**

```
class ReportCSVView(generics.Viewset, mixins.ListModelMixin):
  def get_queryset(self):
    return Report.objects.all()

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    data = ReportSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    renderer = ReportCSVRenderer()

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(renderer.render(data), content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="f.csv"'

    return response
```

**NOTE:** had to comment out or change some things.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

A simpler solution, inspired by the @3066d0's one:

**renderers.py**

```
class ReportsRenderer(CSVStreamingRenderer):
    header = [ ... ]
    labels = { ... }
```

**views.py**

```
class ReportCSVViewset(ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.select_related('stuff')
    serializer_class = ReportCSVSerializer
    renderer_classes = [ReportsRenderer]
    PAGE_SIZE = 1000

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(
            request.accepted_renderer.render(self._stream_serialized_data(queryset)),
            status=200,
            content_type="text/csv",
        )
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="reports.csv"'
        return response

    def _stream_serialized_data(self, queryset):
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, self.PAGE_SIZE)
        for page in paginator.page_range:
            yield from serializer(paginator.page(page).object_list, many=True).data
```

The point is that you need to pass a generator that yields serialized data as the `data` argument to the renderer, and then the `CSVStreamingRenderer` does its things and streams the response itself. I prefer this approach, because this way you do not need to override the code of a third-party library.

Answer (score 2):

Django's `StreamingHttpResponse` can be much slower than a traditional `HttpResponse` for small responses.

Don't use it if you don't need to; the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) actually recommend that `StreamingHttpResponse` should only be used in when it is absolutely required that the whole content isn't iterated before transferring the data to the client."

Also for your problem you may find useful setting the chunk_size, switching to [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse) or returning to a normal Response (if using the REST framework) or HttpResponse.

**Edit 1:** About setting the chunk size:

In the [File api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/file/) you can open the File in chunks so not all the file gets loaded in memory.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: _"Also for your problem you may find useful setting the chunk_size"_ - where does one set `chunk_size`?

Comment: In the [File api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/file/) you can open the File in chunks so not all the file gets loaded in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Updated File docs for v4.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/files/file/

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up coming to a solution I was happy with using the `Paginator` class with the queryset. First, I wrote a renderer that subclassed the `CSVStreamingRenderer`, then used that in my CSVViewset's Renderer.

**renderers.py**

```
from rest_framework_csv.renderers import CSVStreamingRenderer

# *****************************************************************************
# BatchedCSVRenderer
# *****************************************************************************


class BatchedCSVRenderer(CSVStreamingRenderer):

    """
    a CSV renderer that works with large querysets returning a generator
    function. Used with a streaming HTTP response, it provides response bytes
    instead of the client waiting for a long period of time
    """

    def render(self, data, renderer_context={}, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'queryset' not in data:
            return data

        csv_buffer = Echo()
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_buffer)

        queryset = data['queryset']
        serializer = data['serializer']

        paginator = Paginator(queryset, 50)

        #  rendering the header or label field was taken from the tablize
        #  method in django rest framework csv

        header = renderer_context.get('header', self.header)
        labels = renderer_context.get('labels', self.labels)

        if labels:
            yield csv_writer.writerow([labels.get(x, x) for x in header])
        else:
            yield csv_writer.writerow(header)

        for page in paginator.page_range:
            serialized = serializer(
                paginator.page(page).object_list, many=True
            ).data

            #  we use the tablize function on the parent class to get a
            #  generator that we can use to yield a row

            table = self.tablize(
                serialized,
                header=header,
                labels=labels,
            )

            #  we want to remove the header from the tablized data so we use
            #  islice to take from 1 to the end of generator

            for row in itertools.islice(table, 1, None):
                yield csv_writer.writerow(row)

# *****************************************************************************
# ReportsRenderer
# *****************************************************************************


class ReportsRenderer(BatchedCSVRenderer):

    """
    A render for returning CSV data for reports

    """

    header = [ ... ]
    labels = { ... }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets

# *****************************************************************************
# CSVViewSet
# *****************************************************************************


class CSVViewSet(
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet,
):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        return StreamingHttpResponse(
            request.accepted_renderer.render({
                'queryset': queryset,
                'serializer': self.get_serializer_class(),
            })
)

# *****************************************************************************
# ReportsViewset
# *****************************************************************************


class ReportCSVViewset(CSVViewSet):

    """
    Viewset for report CSV output

    """

    renderer_classes = [ReportCSVRenderer]
    serializer_class = serializers.ReportCSVSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Report.objects.filter(...)
```

This might seem like a lot for a streaming response, but we used the `BatchedCSVRender` and `CSVViewset` in a bunch of other places. If you're running your server behind nginx then it might also be useful to adjust the settings there to allow streaming responses.

Hopefully this helps anyone having the same goal. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the CSV headers (via the `header` param) when rendering the data:

```py
renderer.render(data, renderer_context={'header': ['header1', 'header2', 'header3']})
```

If you don't specify the `header` parameter, `djangorestframework-csv` will attempt to "guess" the CSV headers by itself. To "guess" the CSV headers, `djangorestframework-csv` will load all your `data` in memory, resulting in the delay you are experiencing.